# Is there a CSS method of guaranteeing a square that fits in the window without scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I can do this in JavaScript easily enough, but would like to know if it's possible with straight CSS: keep a square div in a window that fits within the window size regardless of what that is.

Any solutions I've found do not account for the height becoming less than the width.

Logically speaking what I want is, when the window width is less than the height, give me a square of that width.  If the height is less, then give me a square of that size.

The closest solution I've seen uses a width and height measured in vw, but it does not work when the window is very wide and short.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using the `vmin` unit.

#### Source

From the [viewport-percentage lengths documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths):

> Viewport-percentage lengths define the  value relative to the size of the viewport, i.e., the visible portion of the document. Viewport lengths are invalid in @page declaration blocks.
>
> **vmin**
> Equal to the smaller of vw and vh.

#### Example

Use the full page link to test it with the example in your browser.

```css
body {
  /* So the whole viewport can be used by the square. */
  margin: 0;
}

#sqr {
  /* Uses the 'outer' (i.e. border-box) size when setting width and height. */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  background-color: red;
  border: yellow 10px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="sqr"><div>
```