# Set DIV to use max square space depending on width and height

Tags: html, css

so i have a DIV element which is exactly at the center of the browser window with percentage values in width and height so it resizes depending on browser size:

https://codepen.io/valentin-wei/pen/GRqrgqK

Now however i want the central element to be a perfect square no matter the size of the browser window.
So if the width is bigger then the height set the width to the height value and vice versa.

so i need something like:

```
max-width: currentHeight;
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS method of guaranteeing a square that fits in the window without scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707253/is-there-a-css-method-of-guaranteeing-a-square-that-fits-in-the-window-without-s)

Comment: Set width and height in `vmin` instead of percent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the `vmin` unit.

[Take a look at the explanation in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707253/is-there-a-css-method-of-guaranteeing-a-square-that-fits-in-the-window-without-s/63707644#63707644)

#### Example

Use the full page link to test it with the example in your browser.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.square {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  border: lightblue 1em solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: this also should be deleted because you are copying your own answer from a different quesiton

Comment: @TemaniAfif probably, yes. At least it's my own answer, right? *You cannot delete this accepted answer*

Comment: your own answer or not, you are not allowed to repeat it as many time as you want. We close question as duplicate when the answer is the same (I will take care of the deletion in 2 days when the system allow me)

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. Then I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

I change your code a little:

```
html, body
    {
       margin: 0;
    }

    #surroundingCenterElement
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vw;
        background-color: red;
    }

    #squareCenterElement
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 80vw;
        height: 80vw;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        background-color: blue;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```